# How to share a class from mochaGlobalSetup fixture to spec files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm using mocha framework to test my Node.js application.

I'm trying to create a single class before all tests run in several spec files, that contains useful spies, stubs and data to all my spec files, something like this:

```
// mocha-setup.mjs    
class MyClass {
  data

  constructor() {
    this.data = 'any-data'
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data
  }

  release() {
    // Release data
  }
}
let myClass

export const mochaGlobalSetup = async () => {
  myClass = new MyClass()
}

export const mochaGlobalTeardown = async () => {
  myClass.release()
}
```

I think the place where I should place this class is in the `mochaGlobalSetup` fixture, but I don't find the way to share this class with all spec files, in this way:

```
// file1.spec.ts
describe('test-descriptor-1', function () {
  it('should pass test', function () {
    const data = myClass.getData() // Get some data from myClass created in mochaGlobalSetup
  }
}

// file2.spec.ts
describe('test-descriptor-2', function () {
  it('should pass test', function () {
    const data = myClass.getData() // Get some data from myClass created in mochaGlobalSetup
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Some idea how could I create a class before all tests and share it with all spec files?

PS: I don't want to create a new class every single test, this class is heavy and I want improve performance.